# C programming : How to print a character value passed as a parameter

Tags: c, char, printf

For example there is a method dog:

```
void dog(char C,int N)
{
//here if I want to print the value of C with a print statement,how do I do that?
}
```

Comment: Why do you want the parameter `int N`.

Comment: @Stan Perhaps `C` should be printed `N` times? That's my guess...

Comment: @ChronoKitsune so op should describe the question more clearly:)

Comment: is it really "void dog(char C,int N)"  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this.

Lets say the value stored in the `char c` was the letter "H".

The most basic method would require you to use `putchar` if you only want to see the value:

`putchar(c);`

`putchar` would give you only the value of c, and a newline.

So it would print out:

`H`

However if you wanted the value within the same line with other text you can use `printf`:

`printf("The value stored in C is: %c\n", C);`

It would print out:

`The value stored in C is: H`

`printf` lets you add in the value with the line of text, however there is not newline, so you must add one yourself, as I did.

Hope that clears things up a little bit.

Answer (score 3):

What about a

```
printf("the value of c = %c\n", C);
```

Comment: iharob - funny, we were making the correction at the same moment. you pressed enter first.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
void dog(char C,int N)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "C = %c N = %d\n", C, N );
}
```